# jQuery UI .resizable() & Bootstrap conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have detected a conflict between jQuery and Bootstrap 3.

This jsFiddle will show:

http://jsfiddle.net/flashspys/S8eHJ/2/

important stuff:

```
$(".textdiv").draggable({containment: "parent"}).resizable({handles: "all"});
…
.textdiv {padding: 10px;}
```

If you resize the box you'll notice that the box is jumping a little bit. This behaviour only exist if the bootstrap.css is included. 
I discovered that this effect depends on the padding and the border of the inner div. If you increase the padding the box will jump harder.

Is this bug already known? I asked Google but I found nothing.

Comment: Looks like [bug #8932](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8932), assigned but not fixed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap is applying `box-sizing: border-box;` to your div. Add `box-sizing: content-box;` to your textdiv css to fix it.

Here's how it looks:
http://jsfiddle.net/S8eHJ/3/

Comment: maybe you also know what is wrong here with .resizable(): [link](http://jsfiddle.net/flashspys/S8eHJ/5/) This happens everytime when the area is within a through `margin: 0 auto` centered div

Comment: You still haven't put `box-sizing: content-box;` against the textdiv. http://jsfiddle.net/S8eHJ/6/

Comment: sry i didn't update the fiddle. But in your example is still a bug. After you drag the element once the resize is buggy. Try it out ;)

Comment: What is buggy about it? It works fine for me (in IE and Chrome)

Comment: Ha, excellent way to demo it! Seems it only gets buggy when your screen is large enough (i.e. the result panel is of a certain size) and I didn't see that as my browser is in my second, much smaller screen. No idea what's going on though, I'm guessing JQueryUI bug.

Comment: Also worth noting that it happens witr or without Bootstrap attached.